# How to convert numerical addresses in the stacktrace to symbols?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb, addr2line

I have program that crashes from time to time with a following message in syslog.

Is this possible to modify it in a way, so instead of addresses there would be a readable message about function/line where did it crash?

I have access to program sources, and can lookup for a function via addr2line. However, what interests me is that I want to make it resolve pointers to functions live, so it would be seen in syslog.
Please, share your thoughts on how to implement this

UPD: I saw that it is possible to do by registering a signal handler and executing backtrace() function. Is this a way to do this without modification of a program? Or is it possible to do some generic modification, so every program would execute backtrace upon crashing?

```
[ 1775.374665] virt-manager[870]: unhandled level 3 translation fault (11) at 0x00000000, esr 0x92000007
[ 1775.383904] pgd = fffffe03dcee0000
[ 1775.387302] [00000000] *pgd=0000004018ea0003, *pud=0000004018ea0003, *pmd=0000004018ea0003, *pte=0000000000000000
[ 1775.397616] 
[ 1775.399119] CPU: 2 PID: 870 Comm: virt-manager Tainted: G        W       4.0.0-0.rc5.git4.1.fc22.aarch64 #1
[ 1775.408843] Hardware name: AppliedMicro Mustang/Mustang, BIOS 1.1.0-rh-0.15 Feb 20 2015
[ 1775.416836] task: fffffe03dc44da80 ti: fffffe03dc3d4000 task.ti: fffffe03dc3d4000
[ 1775.424320] PC is at 0x3ffad37ae5c
[ 1775.427715] LR is at 0x3ffad37ae5c
[ 1775.431128] pc : [<000003ffad37ae5c>] lr : [<000003ffad37ae5c>] pstate: 60000000
[ 1775.438493] sp : 000003ffe89cd3d0
[ 1775.441820] x29: 000003ffe89cd3d0 x28: 000000003ceb0620 
[ 1775.447146] x27: 000000003c9600a0 x26: 0000000000000000 
[ 1775.452490] x25: 000003ffb03b0000 x24: 000000003cdf10a0 
[ 1775.457804] x23: 000003ffb03af000 x22: 000000003cab57a0 
[ 1775.463156] x21: 0000000000000000 x20: 0000000000000001 
[ 1775.468477] x19: 000000003cece200 x18: 000003ffb01e2460 
[ 1775.473819] x17: 000003ffb715b790 x16: 000003ffb03305b0 
[ 1775.479140] x15: 0000000000000020 x14: 0000000000000050 
[ 1775.484479] x13: 000000003ceeca18 x12: 000000003ca86110 
[ 1775.489799] x11: 000000003ceec9e0 x10: 000000003ceeb270 
[ 1775.495142] x9 : 000003ffb7202560 x8 : 0000000000000062 
[ 1775.500464] x7 : 0000000000000199 x6 : 0000000000000199 
[ 1775.505805] x5 : 000000003ca9f280 x4 : 0000000000000000 
[ 1775.511145] x3 : 0000000000000000 x2 : b5107af573d8a600 
[ 1775.516458] x1 : 0000000000000000 x0 : 000000003cacbc20 
[ 1775.521797]
```

Comment: well, it is possible to even catch the core file and have a program run automatically for each core...

Comment: You probably want to use libSegFault.so. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/18706496/72178.

Comment: Thanks! Although, it looks like even with this enabled, it outputs addresses in numerical form, not a file + line number in a backtrace

Comment: You need to build a non stripped binary with debug information enabled (with `-g` option).